# Location URI with 201 response in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I can't seem to find how to build the URL of a newly created resource in Ktor.

```
post("/resources") {
  val newResRequest = call.receive<Resource>()

  val newResLocation = service.create(newResRequest)
    .id
    .let { constructAUrlWith(it) }

  with(call) {
    response.header("Location", newResLocation)
    respond(Created)
  }
```

Coming from the Spring world, where URLs can be constructed without knowing the request context or hostnames and such, I was wondering how could I achieve something similar in Ktor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I'm facing the exact same problem

Comment: The locations API of ktor provides means to achieve this, however, that API doesn't match exactly my project. It could work for others, though.

Comment: The locations API is experimental

Comment: Indeed, and this is another reason I am not that fond of it.